# `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kubernetes'` after `conda install -c conda-forge kubernetes`

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I have the following Python script:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
```

After `conda install -c conda-forge kubernetes`, the script errors with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 4, in <module>
    from kubernetes import client, config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kubernetes'
```

Some other info:

```
conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/nyap/tasks/order-manager/grail/anaconda3/envs/python-3.7:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2022.12.7            h033912b_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.12.7          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cyrus-sasl                2.1.27              h9b9944d_10
krb5                      1.19.4               hdba6334_0
kubernetes                1.23.6               h694c41f_0    conda-forge
kubernetes-client         1.23.6               h12d39d3_0    conda-forge
kubernetes-node           1.23.6               h12d39d3_0    conda-forge
kubernetes-server         1.23.6               h12d39d3_0    conda-forge
libcxx                    14.0.6               h9765a3e_0
libedit                   3.1.20221030         h6c40b1e_0
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2
libntlm                   1.6                  h9ed2024_0
libprotobuf               3.11.4               hd9629dc_0
mysql                     5.7.24               h56848d4_0
mysql-connector-c         6.1.11               hccea1a4_1
mysql-connector-python    8.0.18           py37h2de1c92_1
ncurses                   6.4                  hcec6c5f_0
openssl                   1.1.1t               hfd90126_0    conda-forge
pip                       22.3.1           py37hecd8cb5_0
protobuf                  3.11.4           py37h0a44026_0
python                    3.7.7                hf48f09d_4
readline                  8.2                  hca72f7f_0
setuptools                65.6.3           py37hecd8cb5_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
sqlite                    3.41.1               h6c40b1e_0
tk                        8.6.12               h5d9f67b_0
wheel                     0.38.4           py37hecd8cb5_0
xz                        5.2.10               h6c40b1e_1
zlib                      1.2.13               h4dc903c_0
```

What needs to be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

https://anaconda.org/search?q=kubernetes has some hits including `python-kubernetes`.

`conda install python-kubernetes` fixes the issue.